# Бегущая строка CSS

Tags: css

В данном случае текст, который не помещается в ширину заданной области - обрезается. Возможно ли на CSS, сделать из этого бегущую строку, чтобы пользователь видел весь текст?

```css
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</span>
```

Comment: Через transform:translateX и animation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При помощи `@keyframes`.
При наведение останавливается.

```css
.runline {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}

.runline>span {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: runline 20s linear infinite 1s both;
}

.runline:hover>span {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes runline {
  to {transform: translateX(-100%);}
}
```

```html
<div class="runline">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

можно с помощью title при наведении на элемента

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: #c4c4c4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<span title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</span>
</body>
</html>
```